# Checking json before casting to custom object

Tags: android, json, object

I am using json strings for storing and retrieving object/class values. I want to check to be sure that the given json string will match the object provided. I would like to do this without having to use a try..catch block if possible. This is how I have it at the moment. The try...catch works, but I've read somewhere that it is recommended to get rid of as many try...catch's as possible.

Let's say we have a class as follows

```
public class Person
    public String Name;
    public int Age;
end class
```

Then we are given the following json string

```
{
"phonenumber":"777 777 7777"
"gender":"F"
}
```

obviously the json string can't be cast into the given class.
is the try...catch the only way to check if castable or is there another way? (be my luck, it is something that is VERY obvious).

Comment: I think there is no risk of using try-catch block. Actually you can parse the json string to `Person` object if using `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`. When json string does not match object properties, the object such as `Person` would be null.

Answer (score 0):

Situations like this is why try-catch/exception handling structures exist, so I suggest no need to worry.  There are many reasons why you might get a malformed JSON that can't be parsed (e.g. the backend API might have changed, some network problem that cut off the stream etc...) and your client code can't be expected to handle all of these individually.  Exceptions generalise these situations and allow you to respond to these gracefully.

Java does have a notorious reputation of having everything loaded with exceptions that become tedious boilerplate, so a good SDK or library author will find a way to abstract multiple 'low-level exceptions' with fewer 'higher-level' exceptions so that the users of that code won't have to handle all of it themselves

For example, you're parsing a JSON object and let's assume you got that from a network API call.  And because of that your network code might need to handle IOException, URLException etc... So what you might do is hide all of that code in some kind of 'APIService' class that handles all of those exceptions internally, but only bubble up a single 'APIException' to whoever is calling the code and pass the details of any problem that occurs within APIException.

As the author of 'APIService' you'll still have to handle all those different exceptions, but whoever is using your code will only have to handle 'APIException'.  Not only does this hide implementation details (a good thing) but whoever is using your code will have to write less boilerplate (also a good thing)